# jruby on rails retrive attributes in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash, jruby

I've successfully connect my model with a remote netezza database, were I can retrive data from the database in "rails c":

e.g

```
> Cars.first
> #<Cars ID:10, MODEL:"FORD xxxxxxx">
```

HOWEVER, I can not hash retrieve attributes:

```
>Cars.first.MODELNAME            (=> nil)
>Cars.first['MODELNAME']         (10)
```

Is there anyway I can force active record hash the objects or me ?

Comment: Have you tried `Cars.first.id`? As for a hash of **all** attributes, try `Cars.first.attributes`.

Comment: Hi, I shouldn't use ID, sorry. ID probably will work, but Cards.first.model certainly won't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how can you have such attributes "MODEL" or "MODELNAME". Firstly capitalized attrs are not allowed as they represent constant. Secondly "Model" is a reserved word of course, you can't use this word freely. Thirdly the model name "Cars" in not a convention. Model names are supposed to be singular.

Anyway, if your model name is "Car" and attribute name is "model_name" which is legal, you can get the value from hash by a symbol

```
Car.first[:model_name]
```